# Ajax Posting Images

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

So the function below works exactly as I want it to except it only sends one of the initial files (the argument is an array of files). When I try to adjust the current function it affects the script in ways that I don't really understand...

Honestly I might just iterate through the array and then ignore the rest of the script, but I wanted to post to see if anyone else could explain what's going on because it irritates me that I can't figure it out...

Any help would be appreciated!!

```
    function readfiles(files) {
       // debugger;
        var formData = tests.formdata ? new FormData() : null;
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
          if (tests.formdata) formData.append('file ', files[i]);
          previewfile(files[i]);
        }

        // now post a new XHR request
        if (tests.formdata) {
          var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhr.open('POST', './file_upload_parser.php');
          xhr.onload = function() {
            progress.value = progress.innerHTML = 100;
          };

          if (tests.progress) {
            xhr.upload.onprogress = function (event) {
              if (event.lengthComputable) {
                var complete = (event.loaded / event.total * 100 | 0);
                progress.value = progress.innerHTML = complete;
              }
            }
          }

          xhr.send(formData);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
formData.append('file[]', files[i]);
```

the `[]` represents arrays in php for request data.

Comment: So currently i'm accessing the image with this syntax:                                          $name= $_FILES["file"]["name"]; Now that it's an array would it be something like $_FILES["files][0][name];?